# .replace() regex question

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I can have a string that looks like this as an example:

```
sometext<a title="Wink"><img src="http:\\www.seemstatic.com\images\transparent.png" class="emoWink"></a>somemore text<a title="Wink"><img src="http:\\www.seemstatic.com\images\transparent.png" class="emoWink"></a>endof text...
```

I have the following Javascript that matches the above string, and replaces it with `:)`:

```
subject = subject.replace(/<a title="Smile"><img.*<\/a>/, ':)');
```

The catch is it's not greedy... it matches both occurrences rather then just one.

How would I change this code to match just the first occurrence?

Comment: you need to make it non greedy by adding a question mark ?

Comment: Can you provide a better example, i.e. a real world case. Or is *comtextsomemore textendof text...* actually what you want to replace?

Comment: where would I add the questions mark in this:

Comment: @Adam, after the `.*`. But what does this have to do with jquery?

Comment: I actually want to replace this: <a title="Wink"><img src="http:\\www.seemeagainstatic.com\images\transparent.png" class="emoWink"></a> with ;).... but there can be multiple occurances in the same string

Comment: Qtax - I'm running this code in a JQUERY script... subject is a var with the string in it... works fine except for the greedy regex factor

Comment: is there a preferable way to do this kind of regex matching in JQUERY?

Comment: Close your image tag. And I think you mean that the regex _is_ greedy, when you do not want it to be. And "jQuery" is not stylised in all-caps.

Comment: Nothing about this has anything to do with jQuery. jQuery is a library for Javascript. **You're writing Javascript.**

Comment: @Adam, You should use a proper parser to do this, not regex. With jQuery you could do something like `$("a.emoWink").replaceWith(";)");`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to make it non greedy by adding a question mark ?

```
// Greedy quantifiers
String match = find("A.*c", "AbcAbc");  // AbcAbc
match = find("A.+", "AbcAbc");          // AbcAbc

// Nongreedy quantifiers
match = find("A.*?c", "AbcAbc");        // Abc
match = find("A.+?", "AbcAbc");         // Abc
```

So in your case, something like

```
subject = subject.replace(/<a title="Smile"><img.*?<\/a>/, ':)');
```

Comment: Except that you put the `?` in the wrong place, it goes after the quantifier as in the pasted examples. ;)

Comment: thanks guys its working now... subject = subject.replace(/<a title="Smile"><img.+?<\/a>/g, ':)'); cheers adam

Answer (score 3):

Don't do this with regex.  You're already using jQuery, so you can use jQuery's DOM traversal methods:

```
yourString = $('<span>' + yourString + '</span>')
                 .find('a[title="Wink"]')
                     .replaceWith(';)')
                 .end()
                 .html();
```

Comment: Updated for OPs comments: `find('a[title="Wink"]:has(img.emoWink)')` or add `.filter(':has(img.emoWink')`

Comment: @Qtax I'm not sure that's necessary, but yes, that would work. It would be better to use the first one, as it will invoke `querySelectorAll` and therefore be significantly faster.

Comment: It's better use `.filter()` according to the docs: Because :has() is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS specification, queries using :has() cannot take advantage of the performance boost provided by the native DOM querySelectorAll() method. To achieve the best performance when using :has() to select elements, first select the elements using a pure CSS selector, then use .filter(":has()")

Comment: @Qtak Ah, had forgotten that `:has` was a Sizzle extension. In that case, it would be better, surely, to use the `has()` method

Answer (score 0):

Technically this is not a jquery question, it is a javascript question, since the replace here is on a String object.

You can greedy replace with `subject.replace(/search/g, 'replacement');`

The g modifier makes it replace all instances.

You problem might be better solved with a jQuery approach though, using css selectors: 
eg. `$('.a[title=Smile]').replaceWith(';)')`